# How does subprocess handle file pointer?

Tags: python, subprocess, io-redirection, filehandle

Suppose the code skeleton in Python looks like this. This code is invoking another executable bash script to run in parallel, on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#encoding:utf-8

import subprocess 
with open(file='subprocess_output.log', mode='a') as file_pointer:
    subprocess.Popen(args=['./subprocess.bash'], stdout=file_pointer, stderr=file_pointer)

#Next section
```

It is working. But I am curious, whether the `with` statement is closing the file pointer and releasing the resource as soon as the main code moves on to the next section. Is not that exactly what a `with` statement is supposed to do? To acquire and release the resources *safely*? But if the handle to the log file is released immediately following the invocation, how is the subprocess buffer writing to the log later, when the main script has moved on?

Probably the answer is obvious to anyone with a deeper understanding how files are handled by the OS at a lower level. So any pointer to an online resource (pun intended) will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own set of open files.  Subprocesses are created with **copies** of (a subset of) their parent’s open file handles (“descriptors” in Unix, with the subset governed by the [`FD_CLOEXEC` flag](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)).  The `with` closes the parent’s handles immediately, but this doesn’t affect the child at all.

Sometimes it matters whether **any** copies remain: reading from a pipe, for example, produces EOF when *every* copy of the writing end has been closed.